# Android Studio generated APK crashes while running the application on the same phone works fine. What is wrong?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, apk

First of all, I'm quite new to all of this.

I'm using android studio 2.1. When I'm running the code for the application on my phone, everything is working perfectly. However, when I create a signed APK and install the app on my phone (after deleting the files from the software runs), it somehow starts lagging massively, a black screen appeares, the UI stops working, memory and CPU usage spike and the app & phone stop working all together.

When I create an APK, I set it as a debug version. I have tried both signed APK and non signed APK. In both cases the same thing is happening.

Not only that, the application suddenly takes up 12 megabytes, while the application only has 6 activities and no images except the launch icon.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem then i compile with
"classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'"
this gradle and it works properly..,